# VisualStudio2010 IIS Could not find the server. Failed to create virtual directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis

When I open solution in VisualStudio2010, I am unable to load View project.
Right-click and 'Reload Project' it asks me:
[image: Do I want to create a virtual directory]

When I click on "Yes", it shows me a failure message:
[image: Could not find the server]

Other projects don't have this kind of problem.

In "Turn Windows Feauters On/Off", for IIS I've checked all options.

I noticed that my aspnet_regiis -i command doesnt work.
When I open cmd as Admin, and navigate to the folder "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>" and try yo execute command, I get:
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.
Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).

I have IIS 10 on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your web project and go to Properties. Then click on the Web tab and in Servers section select Local IIS. Then check the Project URL and click on Create Virtual Directory. Also make sure you are running Visual Studio as administrator.